# Unable to read jar manifest with java.util.jar.JarFile

Tags: java, jar

I'm having trouble reading the contents of the manifest in a jar file using the `java.util.jar.JarFile` class. Ultimately the problem I'm trying to solve is to determine if a specific jar file has a `Main-Class` entry in its manifest, but before I get there I'm getting the manifest to be empty.

Consider this minimal test case:

```
public class ReadJar {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      java.util.jar.JarFile jf = new java.util.jar.JarFile("Hello.jar");
      System.out.println("Manifest entries: " + jf.getManifest().getEntries());
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

I'm testing it as follows:

```
$ cat Hello.java 
public class Hello {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello");
  }
}
$ cat mainifest.txt 
Main-Class: Hello
$ javac Hello.java 
$ jar cfm Hello.jar mainifest.txt Hello.class 
$ java -jar Hello.jar 
Hello
$ javac ReadJar.java 
$ java ReadJar 
Manifest entries: {}
$
```

It appears that I'm creating the jar correctly since it can be run with the `java -jar` command. Manual inspection of the manifest also appears correct to me:

```
$ unzip -d temp Hello.jar 
Archive:  Hello.jar
   creating: temp/META-INF/
  inflating: temp/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF  
  inflating: temp/Hello.class        
$ cat temp/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF 
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.8.0_40-internal (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: Hello

$
```

So how can you read the manifest correctly? Is there a different class I should be using than `java.util.jar.JarFile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All contents in your MANIFEST.MF are [main attributes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html). so you can use this function to get the attributes `getMainAttributes()`. from there you can get the key set and then try to iterate it and get the value from the key.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. For those that see this later, changing my `println` line to `jf.getManifest().getMainAttributes().keySet()` gets the output I expected of `[Created-By, Manifest-Version, Main-Class]`.